# Maintaining a common value of a static variable across instances in Python

Tags: python, class, static, class-variables

I have read that to create a static variable we can declare them inside the class definition and not inside the method. But it doesn't seem so "static" to me when looked at from Java world since changing a variable's value from one instance creates its own variable different from the class variable. 
I'm looking for a way to ensure that the value of a variable remains consistent across different instances. One of the answers on StackOverflow had suggested the following piece of code which doesn't seem to work well for me.

```
class Test(object):
_i = 3
@property
def i(self):
    return self._i
@i.setter
def i(self,val):
    self._i = val


x1 = Test()
x2 = Test()
x1.i = 50
assert x2.i == x1.i # The example suggested no error here but it doesn't work for me
```

Can you explain with an example if it's possible to achieve this?

Comment: you seem to waste your time with this since there are no constant vars and there are dynamic properties in python have you considered the option just to not do it (override the var in the instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test(object):
    _i = 3

    @classmethod
    def set_i(self, value):
        self._i = value

    def get_i(self):
        return self._i

    i = property(get_i, set_i)

x1 = Test()
x2 = Test()
print(x1.i) # 3
print(x2.i) # 3

x1.set_i(50)
print(x1.i) # 50
print(x2.i) # 50
```

Comment: This will only create a new variable of i in x1 instance's namespace and hence won't affect anything in x2.

Comment: I see. Okay I've edited the answer with a classmethod to update the static variable of the class. I verified this will work.

Comment: @NavjotSingh okay I got one even better for you now.